# Группировка одинаковых значений

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!

У меня, в общем, вопрос следующего содержания:

Есть одна таблица, в которой содержится список участников, у них, соответственно, свои определенные баллы за тот или иной показатель. Каждый участник прикреплен к определенному пункту, всего их 30. Мне нужно вывести не участников, а именно эти пункты, в которых содержалась бы средняя информация всех участников, входящих в эти пункты.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил:) Если что, прошу прощения!

U.P.

[[@terantul](/users/11594/terantul)](/users/11594/terantul), все та же таблица. Как сказал в ней пользователи, которые закреплены по пунктам. 30 пунктов.
Тот запрос, что выше, отлично работает и выводит среднее, как, собственно, и хотелось.
Но, средневзвешенное значение, намного точнее среднего, и есть ли такая функция, которая могла бы это посчитать.
Средневзвешенное значение считается как:   
= участник_1 * среднее_значение_по_пункту + участник_2 * среднее_значение_по_пункту +...+ участник_n * среднее_значение_по_пункту / среднее_значение_по_пункту.
Это нужно посчитать каждого участника, умножить каждого на среднее по этому пункту, и потом всю эту сумму поделить на среднее этого пункта. И так для всех 30. 
Вот, думаю, средствами mysql можно ли такое сделать...

Comment: Выбрать 30 пунктов и по каждому вывести средний бал?

Comment: @terantul, да, именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
AVG(expr)
Возвращает среднее значение аргумента expr:
mysql> SELECT student_name, AVG(test_score)
        FROM student
        GROUP BY student_name;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Comment: А для средневзвешенного нет функции в mysql?
(балл участника*среднее по пункту)+.../среднее по пункту)
а то у меня показатели от табличных улетели на единицу от среднего)))

Comment: уточните. как то сумбурно вопрос написан.

Comment: @terantul, уточнил в вопросе, сюда такое уточнение не поместилось:)